# Views Contextual Filters with Wildcards URLs

Tags: 7, commerce, views

I have a view with two page displays.  The first page uses a contextual filter for the UID, which is provided with a default value for the user that is currently logged in to the site.  One of the fields displays an order ID, and I have a second Global: Custom Text field which displays a link that appends the order ID to last path component of the URL.

The second page display uses a wildcard within the path of page settings, that matches the scheme of the link generated in the first page display.  When the argument is provided in the preview everything works as expected, however when the URL is accessed via browsing I only see a blank page.

Does anyone have any ideas of why this may be happening or have additional information regarding using path wildcard and contextual filters.  Thanks in advance for any possible advice or tips.

Comment: How does the path looks exactly? Maybe you forgot that to make a path optional you should not add % at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the error had to do with URL that was used in the path.

When I originally had the issue I was using "account/page/%" , but after removing account so that it read "page/%" everything began to work as expected.